# Стрим видео с android на сервер

Tags: java, android

Есть VDS сервер, есть android. Как можно с android'а стримить видео с камеры на сервер? До этого видел лишь реализацию IP камеры на андроид, но это прям вообще не подходит. Нужно через интернет.

Comment: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv -

https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming